# Your Task Is to Create the World's Hardest Irregular Sudoku!

Tags: sudoku, construction

*Ahem, let's formalize your task...*

A Sudoku is a puzzle consisting of a grid to be filled with symbols, such that each constraining unit contains each symbol exactly once. The regular Sudoku is a $9 \times 9$ square to be filled with the numbers $1$ to $9$, where the constraining units are rows, columns, and $3 \times 3$ blocks.

Irregular Sudoku is similar to regular Sudoku but the $3 \times 3$ blocks constraints are changed to $9$ **nonominoes** (polyominos with a size of $9$). Rows and columns constraints still apply.

Some numbers are initially given in the grid. Those numbers are called clues. A valid Sudoku grid must have **exactly** one solution.

Contrast to the answers here: [Why is this considered to be “The World's Hardest Sudoku”?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/305/why-is-this-considered-to-be-the-worlds-hardest-sudoku), we define our own hardness level. A Sudoku is harder if the number of clues in its grid is lesser. That means, the world's hardest irregular Sudoku is defined as the irregular Sudoku with **the least number of clues**.

> **Simple, your task is to create the world's hardest irregular Sudoku! (And prove it!)**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The 'hardest' possible Irregular Sudoku has

> just 8 clues!

and it looks like this:

> [image]
>
>  You can fill in the 9 in the top row, then use the logic from [this answer by hexomino](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/36012/11876) to show that the answer is unique.
>
>  And this is the maximum because if you had less clues, at least two numbers would be missing -- in any solution, you could just interchange those two numbers!

Comment: Amazing, this is correct, well done! My construction is using the same layout, but the numbers are given in the first column instead of the first row, :)

Comment: Given the structured pattern, is it really the "hardest"?

Comment: @Earlien No, not according to the usual meaning of the word - that's why I put the word "hardest" in quotes. But that's how the word "hard" is being defined for this question.

Comment: I thought this looked familiar.