# Help solve sudoku

Tags: sudoku

[image: Sudoku puzzle]

I did solve this sudoku in 24 minutes, but I had to guess from this part out. I'm using a website to display this sudoku a lot neater than the original site. I can solve plenty of sudokus, but the hints were to check if I missed something. I *never* touched this site while I solved the original sudoku (hence the 24min solve time taking so long).

This is an extreme level sudoku and 1 step higher than hard.

I always get this far and end up guessing a cell until I reach a dead end or complete it to eliminate that possibility of the wrong answer.

Is the sudoku not correctly constructed (it should be solvable without guessing according to common standard rules) or am I missing something?

Comment: Check out this question https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/252/how-do-i-solve-the-worlds-hardest-sudoku?rq=1

Comment: So are you asking someone to solve this for you, or are you asking for "techniques" to make solving these easier? Because it seems like you already solved this...

Comment: [Techniques to solve sudoku puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30519/techniques-to-solve-this-sudoku-puzzle/30540#30540) might be useful to read through in this similar question.

Comment: Has a useful answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 10):

A Sudoku game / tutorial / solver I have on my phone called simply [:) Sudoku +](http://www.enjoysudoku.com/) (yeah, with an odd smiley in the name) tells me to look for an [XY Wing](http://sudopedia.enjoysudoku.com/XY-Wing.html) in the lower right corner. This removes one of the possibilities in the eastward box. So yes, this sudoku puzzle is well-defined.

> [image: Spoiler image]