# How can I solve this sudoku?

Tags: sudoku

I've almost finished this hard sudoku, but I cannot finish it without guessing or making multiple blind steps to see if I'm wrong or not. Even https://www.sudoku-solutions.com/ gives up and says "there is no hint available". I've tried to apply as many solving techniques as possible, but to no avail. Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: It is often a mistake, but some sudoku puzzles have multiple solutions... I'll have a look though.

Comment: Thank you, I've also just found this: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/252/how-do-i-solve-the-worlds-hardest-sudoku?rq=1, from which I understood it's acceptable to make multiple assumptions on multiple cells (what I called "blind steps forward") and see if you come to a dead end or not...

Comment: It's not enough to see if you come to a dead end though; you'll need to see if the solution you found was unique; otherwise you'll end up claiming to have solved a sudoku that wasn't actually a sudoku.

Comment: There is the following nice trick: If every open cell in the sudoku has exactly two possibilities left except for one cell which has three, this cell has one possible number that is a possibility an odd number of times. This is the correct digit for that cell. In this puzzle, 2 is still possible in eleven cells, 4 is possible in six and 8 is possible in 10. Hence, E7 has to be a 2.

Comment: Look up the solving technique called **Sashimi-X-Wing**.  If F1 does not contain a 2, then you have a basic X-Wing on E1, G1, E9 and G9 which eliminates the 2 in E2.  Of course if F1 _is_ a 2, then the 2 in E2 is also eliminated.  So in no case can E2 contain a 2.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If F1 is a 2, then

> G1 is "not 2", G9 must be 2, and E9 cannot be a 2.

On the other hand, if F1 is **not** a 2, then

> E2 must be a 2, so E9 cannot be 2.

Therefore,

> **E9 cannot be 2.**

Comment: Genius, thank you. Is there a name for this logic, such as swordfish? Or just logic? :)

Comment: @Andrejs http://www.sudokusnake.com/coloring.php

Comment: @Andrejs I tried to colour them [here](https://imgur.com/a/eDD1mPX) E9 cannot be be both red and blue, if we consider number 2.

Comment: @Andrejs I think it might be called "universal elimination" in formal logic, but sudoku terms are not my strong suit :-)

Comment: @Andrejs To add to this answer, look up "Bivalue Universal Grave + 1" or BUG+1. If every cell has only 2 options except for one cell that has 3 options, you call that a BUG+1.

Answer (score 7):

Solution method that uses value propagation and digit elimination, but not explicit case-by-case analysis:

> G1 = E9.  (That's because of how they interact with G9.)  That digit is not 2 because that would squeeze out digit 2 from the DEF123 square altogether.  Therefore it is 8.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

> [image]

It is the only solution because it follows logically from placing an 8 on A7, and placing a 2 on A7 led to this contradiction for me (no 2 on row 8). Bass provides more intelligent reasoning for this step.

[image]