# Sudoku Move Marked Wrong, Seems Legal: Software Bug?

Tags: sudoku

[image: move]

The included screenshot shows an attempted Sudoku move. The computer is marking it incorrect. There is no other 7 in the row, column, or 3x3 cell. What gives?

Comment: [This question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/74890/sudoku-false-positive-wrong-move) might help, it seems to be asking the exact same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This program likely has the solution built into it, so it knows that this 7 is wrong.

Each Sudoku puzzle has a *single* solution that can be figured out with pure logic.¹ Even if you place something without it directly contradicting anything else, it may be the case that you would find out *later* that that was wrong. You should only place numbers that you've deduced to go in that location -- that you're 100% sure of. Anything else could be a mistake, and would lead to the puzzle being unsolvable.

¹ (Or at least, it *should*, but apps are often poorly designed.)

Comment: With this program you can solve every sudoku puzzle by brainlessly click every possibility on every cell...

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that the unique solution to the sudoku does not have a 7 there. At the moment it is not immediately clear what number should be in that corner, and there is no direct reason for it to be a 7 rather than a 2 or a 6.

In fact, with some thought you can show it will actually have to be a 6:

> Column E only has one spot for its 6, namely cell E5.
>  Row 6 now has only one spot for its 6, namely cell C6.
>  Row 1 now has only one spot for its 6, namely cell A1.

Answer (score 1):

> The $6$'s at r4c9 and r8c2 mean that the $6$ in block left-middle is on the right, so the $6$ in row 1 is also in column 1 (due to r3c6 or r7c4, r4c9 and r9c8).